# Moving image for android

Tags: android, image

<--------------------------- image direction ---------------------------------------

------------------------------> Image.PNG <---------------------------------------

[]--------------------------------------------------------------{}----------------------[]

{} xxxxxxx  Image.PNG  xxxxxxxx         Image.PNG xxxxxxxX                {} Image.PNG xxxxx[]

{} ------------------------------------------------------------{}----------------------[]

-------------------------------------------------------> end ^ beginnin (of the image)

I am using an image that runs contineously in one place from one side to another (see picture) like a marquee but instead of text I use an image, it this possible? else how will I incorporate this image to my activity. Help... Thanks..

Comment: Hi,you can do it using animations.  see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/TranslateAnimation.htm

Comment: [Frame by Frame animation](http://www.twintechs.com/blog/?p=35) will may be help you becase useing this you can give image to effect of marquee.

Comment: Thank you Dr. Nik. I tried using a frame by frame animation but i was never successful in how the result would appear. maybe I am doing it wrong since I have to do it one activity per frame? Again thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can use android canvas. Draw bitmap on android canvas and check for condition that

```
 if(x>canvas.getHeight()||x<0) {x=0}else{increment or decrement accordingly}
```