# How to do webview  animation in android

Tags: android, animation

suppose i have three text as heading.Any how you can take textview or anything.one text on left,one in center and one in right side.so i want an animation when i will slide the screen left then left text will be gone,center text will come to left and right text will come to center.Same thing for right slide.Can anyone suggest how can i achieve this type of animation.Plz help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7592957/moving-image-for-android/7593041#7593041

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create an animation variable :

```
  private Animation leftAnimation() {

        Animation outtoLeft = new TranslateAnimation(
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f,
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f,
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 1.0f,
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f);
        outtoLeft.setDuration(500);
        outtoLeft.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
        return outtoLeft;
    }
```

then 
set this action to your frame:

```
public void onLeftArrowClick(View v) {
        frame.setAnimation(moveComingSoonToBottomAnim); // your Frame variable
        animVariable.startNow();// your anime variable
        frame.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        rightFrame.setVisibility(View.GONE); // hide your right text view
    }
```